# Override Drupal views fields module with custom module

Tags: 7, views, entities, theming

In Drupal 7.22, I want to override 'views-view-fields.tpl.php' views module with custom 'coutforum' module.

The steps I've followed include:

1- renaming the 'views-view-fields.tpl.php' to 'views-view-fields--coutforum.tpl.php' in my custom 'coutforum' module, as per the Drupal convention of adding the double dash & suffix of my custom module.

2- Updated the code in 'coutforum.module' file:

```
function coutforum_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['view']->name)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] []= 'views_view_fields__coutforum';
    }
  }
function coutforum_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
    $theme_registry['views_view_fields__coutforum'] = array(
        'theme paths' => $theme_path,
        'template' =>'views-view-fields--coutforum',
        'path' => $theme_path,
    );
}
```

Code written so far is working correctly, however have the following error:

1. Notice: Undefined index: type in theme() (line 1158 of /var/www/drupal-7.22/includes/theme.inc).
2. Notice: Undefined index: #title in template_preprocess_field() (line 1037 of /var/www/drupal-7.22/modules/field/field.module).

Question: **How can I define the theme 'type' in template_preprocess_field() / theme registry?**

Comment: Is content of 'views-view-fields.tpl.php' identical to 'views-view-fields--coutforum.tpl.php' for now?

Comment: @Mołot no content is not same. i have totally changed code in 'views-view-fields--coutforum

Comment: Is this happening when you put original .tpl.php file under 'views-view-fields--coutforum.tpl.php' name, and move your own out? If not, then it's something within your tpl file, and we will not be able to answer without seeing it. If yes, then we can look using standard files.

Comment: ok my **views-view-fields--coutforum.tpl.php** code is : '<h3 class="cHeading"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></h3><div class="cComments">
    <div class="cCommentsNo"><?php print $fields['comment_count']->content; ?></div>
    <div class="cCommentTxt">comments</div>
</div>
<div class="cBy">
    <div class="cByTxt">by&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cConvAuthor"><?php print $fields['uid']->content; ?></div>
    <div class="cInTxt">&nbsp;in</div>
    <div class="cInCategory"><?php print $fields['taxonomy_forums']->content; ?></div>
</div>

'

Comment: i past in the same code from **views-view-fields.tpl.php** in **views-view-fields--coutforum.tpl.php**, but still issue..